# my form is not posting values even though i have put method="post" in my form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

my form is not posting values even though i have put method="post" and i think there is no error in my form.i have hide some input types by javascript. i am not understanding where the problem is can you rectify that ..my code is

```
  <?php include "header.php" ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
 <head>
 <style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-9" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <h3 align="center">Blood Bank  Registration </h3>
    <form role="form"  action="bbinsert.php" method="post"  style="color:black">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bbname" id="college"   placeholder="Blood bank name" required>
     </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <select class="form-control" id="district" name="district" required>
         <option >Select District</option>
         <option value="prakasam">Prakasam</option>
         <option value="guntur">Guntur</option>
         <option value="Nellore">Nellore</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <select class="form-control" id="mandal" name="mandal" required>
         <option >Select Mandal</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="village" name="village" required>
        <option >Select Village</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phno" placeholder="contact number" >
     </div>
     <p align="right">create employee<button onclick="return show();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></span></button></p>
     <div  id="empform" style="display:none;" >
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="empname1"  placeholder="Employee Name" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empid1"  placeholder="Employee Id" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"class="form-control" name="password1"  placeholder="password" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"class="form-control" name="phno1"  placeholder="Contact Number">
    </div>
            <p align="right"><button onclick="return hide();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></span></button><button onclick="return show1();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></span></button></p>
     </div>
```

```
  <div  id="empform2" style="display:none;" >
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="empname3"  placeholder="Employee Name" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empid3"  placeholder="Employee Id" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"class="form-control" name="password3"  placeholder="password" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"class="form-control" name="phno3"  placeholder="Contact Number">
    </div>
    <p align="right"><button onclick="return hide2();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></span></button></p><br>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="create" >
</form>

 <script> 
     function show() { 
       if(document.getElementById('empform').style.display=='none') { 
        document.getElementById('empform').style.display='block'; 
     } 
    return false;
    } 
   function hide() { 
    if(document.getElementById('empform').style.display=='block') { 
        document.getElementById('empform').style.display='none'; 
    } 
    return false;
  } 
   function show1() { 
    if(document.getElementById('empform1').style.display=='none') { 
        document.getElementById('empform1').style.display='block'; 
     } 
    return false;
  } 
   function hide1() { 
    if(document.getElementById('empform1').style.display=='block') { 
        document.getElementById('empform1').style.display='none'; 
    } 
    return false;
} 
 function show2() { 
    if(document.getElementById('empform2').style.display=='none') { 
        document.getElementById('empform2').style.display='block'; 
    } 
    return false;
} 
function hide2() { 
    if(document.getElementById('empform2').style.display=='block') { 
        document.getElementById('empform2').style.display='none'; 
    } 
    return false;
} 


 </script>
```

bbinsert.php

```
 <?php 
    include "connection.php";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 

    {
 $bbname=$_POST['bbname'];
$district=$_POST['district'];
 $mandal=$_POST['mandal'];
$village=$_POST['village'];
$phno=$_POST['phno'];

 $insertbb=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO  bloodbanks(bbname,bbdistrict,bbmandal,bbcity,phno)VALUES('$bbname','$district',$mandal','$village','$phno')");
 if(!$insertbb)
echo "error in blood bank insertion".mysqli_error($conn);
else
echo "successfully inserted blood banks";



    $emp1 = array('empname1', 'empid1', 'password1','phno1');
  $emp2 = array('empname2', 'empid2', 'password2','phno2');
   $emp3 = array('empname3', 'empid3', 'password3','phno3');

  $error = false; //No errors yet
   foreach($emp1 AS $fieldname)
    { //Loop trough each field
  if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) 
   {
   $error = true; //Yup there are errors
  }
}

if(!$error) { 
 $empn1=$_POST['empname1'];
 $empid1=$_POST['empid1'];
 $password1=$_POST['password1'];
 $phno1=$_POST['phno1'];

 $insert1=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO    employees(name,empid,password,phno,bbname)VALUES('$empn1','$emmpid1','$password1  ','$phno1','$bbname')");
if(!$insert1)
   echo "error in emp1".mysqli_error($conn);
else
   echo "success emp1";

}
$error1 = false; //No errors yet
foreach($emp2 AS $fieldname)
  { //Loop trough each field
 if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) 
    {
    $error1 = true; //Yup there are errors
  }
 }

if(!$error1) { 

 $empn2=$_POST['empname2'];
 $empid2=$_POST['empid2'];
 $password2=$_POST['password2'];
 $phno2=$_POST['phno2'];

  $insert2=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO employees(name,empid,password,phno,bbname)VALUES('$empn2','$emmpid2','$password2','$phno2','$bbname')");

if(!$insert2)
   echo "error in emp2".mysqli_error($conn);
```

else
     echo "success emp2";
      }
     $error3 = false; //No errors yet
       foreach($emp3 AS $fieldname)
       { //Loop trough each field
      if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) 
      {
       $error3 = true; //Yup there are errors
      }
    }

```
if(!$error3) { 


  $empn3=$_POST['empname3'];
  $empid3=$_POST['empid3'];
  $password3=$_POST['password1'];
 $phno3=$_POST['phno3'];

 $insert3=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO employees(name,empid,password,phno,bbname)VALUES('$empn3','$emmpid3','$password3','$phno3','$bbname')");
  if(!$insert3)
   echo "error in emp3".mysqli_error($conn);
 else
    echo "success emp3";

    }
    }
   else
{
echo "submit method did not post the form";
}
 ?>
```

`

Comment: You haven't posted your bbinsert.php file. Anyway, could you investigate in that file using var_dump($_POST) to see what is going on?

Comment: ok  i will edit my question and post bbinsert.php

Comment: Do you have Firebug or some other debugger that will allow you to see the POST content of the request? Another way around that would be to simply echo out the $_POST values on the PHP script to see if they're getting there.

Comment: @RobWood OP doesn't need an extension for that. Most modern browsers' built-in dev tools will show the http request details

Comment: yes i have checked that by if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) condition .but it is goint to else statement

Comment: Have you tried a simple var_dump on the POST array, or simply die(print_r($_POST))? That way you can be sure the POST data isn't getting to PHP, so you'll know the issue is on the client side.

If the problem IS on the client side, I'd watch the request as it's made, make sure it's a post request,and then check what the post payload is.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. Your submit button doesn't have a name attribute. So no post element called "submit" exists. Put a name on your submit button if you want it to post.

Comment: excellent its working..Thank you so much

Comment: Added the solution as an answer rather than a comment so you can mark it as correct. =}

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button doesn't have a name attribute. So no post element called "submit" exists. Put a name on your submit button if you want it to post.